# Header location doesn't work in web server

Tags: php

I've got the following and works fine in my localhost. Same I tried on the web server but the `header("Location:xxxx");` doesn't seems to be working. Have I got anything wrong here? I've red some previous posts and try to correct the white space etc; but no joy. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Here is code:

```
    <th><?php
 $db = mysqli_connect('xxxxxgemysql.com', 'headpass', 'headpass1', 'headpass');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {die('The connection to the database could not be established.');}

       if(isset($_POST['submitLog']))
       {
           if(isset($_SESSION['loggedUser']))
           {echo 'A login already exists with user  &nbsp;'.$_SESSION['loggedUser'].'.&nbsp;<a href="logout.php" style="color:#1E65C9; font-family:Palatino Linotype; text-decoration:none;" > Log off</a> first';}
           else { 
       $un_cuser = $_POST['textfield']; 
       $un_cpwd = $_POST['password2'];
          if($un_cuser== '') 
           {echo 'User name is required';}
           elseif($un_cpwd == '')
           {echo 'Password is required';}
            else
              { 
              $SQL_log = "SELECT un,pw FROM userlogs WHERE un='$un_cuser'";
              $result_log = mysqli_query($db,$SQL_log) or die ("SQL Error : Log-ER_001");
              $row_log = mysqli_fetch_array($result_log);
                      if($row_log == '')
                       {echo 'Sorry!';}  

                        elseif($un_cpwd == $row_log['pw'])
                        {
                            $result_log_b = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT un AS fnam FROM userlogs WHERE un='$un_cuser'"); 
                            $row_log_b = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_log_b); 
                            $sum_log_b = $row_log_b['fnam'];
                            $_SESSION['loggedUser'] = $row_log_b['fnam'];
                            header('Location:http://www.google.com');}else
                        {echo 'Password error!';}}}}?></th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're outputting a `<th>` at the very start of the script.

> [Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)